# Create a custom background drawable for a EditText

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'm trying to set a custom drawable to a EditText as expected below:

[image: except]

So I wrote this custom drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="36dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp">
<item>
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="6dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#BBBBBB"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:width="32dp"
    android:gravity="left">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="32dp"/>
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="6dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="6dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#AAAAAA"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:left="8dp">
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_email"
        android:tileMode="disabled"/>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

The result in preview is quite good (except different corner size, not handled by Android Studio)

[image: result in preview]

But in device, it totally not works...
The second item is stretched and does not respect the width attribute.

[image: result in device]

I know, I can do it with a 9-patch, but I want to know if is it possible with drawables?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Managed to do it with a single background drawable and a compound drawable on the EditText.

`bg_edittext_icon.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#AAAAAA" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="34dp">
        <!-- left is icon size + 2x side padding around icon-->
        <!-- 18 + 8 + 8 -->
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp"
                android:topRightRadius="6dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="6dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#BBBBBB" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In your layout, use it like that:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_edittext_icon"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email_white_18dp"
    android:drawablePadding="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="12dp"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
    android:hint="Email"
    />
```

With `paddingLeft` the icon padding inside the grey box and `drawablePadding` the padding inside the grey box + padding of the edit zone.

Here is the result from Genymotion (aka, real device):

[image: Result from real device]

Hope you like it !