# How to add border to EditText in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

[image: edittext pic]

Hi, I want to add an textbox just like the image above in android app. I used the edittext control,but cannot show border.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to add a border to the top and bottom of an Android View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598119/is-there-an-easy-way-to-add-a-border-to-the-top-and-bottom-of-an-android-view)

Answer (score 60):

Create a new xml file `edit_text_border.xml` in drawable folder, or give name of your choice. Then add the following code:

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="12dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="12dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="12dp"
        android:topRightRadius="12dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:color="#ffffff"
        android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

You can adjust the stroke color and radius values to your requirements. Finally, in your `edittext` set it as background like following.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_border"/>
```

Comment: @android:color/transparent

Answer (score 16):

Nowadays, the correct way would be to use `TextInputLayout` with the corresponding style.
It will not only draw an outline background but will preserve a nice hint animation.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/some_hint"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="5dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="5dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="5dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            tools:ignore="KeyboardInaccessibleWidget" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

If you want to change the line color - it's a little tricky:

Create a style:

```
<style name="Til" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
      <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_box_stroke</item>
</style>
```

Where color `res/color/text_input_box_stroke.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--    TODO play with these around -->
    <item android:color="#0cc" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:color="#fcc" android:state_hovered="true"/>
    <item android:color="#f0f"/>
</selector>
```

Apply your new style to TextInputLayout as `style="@style/Til"`

Not forget to add a dependency to your app/build.gradle:

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try following code:

1. Create shape.xml file in drawable folder and write following code in it:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <!-- Background Color -->
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

   <!-- Border Color -->
   <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff9900" />

   <!-- Round Corners -->
   <corners android:radius="5dp" />
   </shape>
   ```

   2. Now inside your EditText use this xml by adding `android:background="@drawable/shape"`

Answer (score 1):

create xml file in drawable
shape_border_and_background_login.xml  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <corners android:radius="25dip" />
    <solid android:color="#55ffffff">

    </solid>
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

add shape file to EditText background:

```
 <EditText
                      android:id="@+id/edt_email"
                      android:layout_width="0dp"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_weight="10"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_border_and_background_login"
                      android:inputType="textPersonName"
                      android:padding="@dimen/size15"
                      android:textSize="@dimen/size17"
                     />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in multiple ways.

You can create a drawable in xml ( a selector drawable that has shape items with round corners and border) - [Similar Question (and example code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589596/create-a-custom-background-drawable-for-a-edittext)

Or you can create a 9-patch image and just use that. ([Documentation and Example](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html))